# Why can't I disconnect my database handles with DBD::DB2?

Tags: perl, dbi, disconnect

My perl script is slow but works.  I am considering throwing it out and building a true DB2 application with proper binds and such; however, in the meantime I want this to work as a place holder.

I looked at [this documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ibmtordb2/DBD-DB2-1.71/DB2.pod) and it mentions:

```
$dbh->disconnect();
```

However I cannot use it because it throws this error.

> Can't locate object method
>   "disconnect" via package "dbh"
>   (perhaps  load "dbh"?) at
>   ./ProgramTree.pl line 119.

I know my temporary application is leaking and growing because it is recursively opening database handles.  Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error sounds an awful lot like the sigil is missing and you're running just `dbh->disconnect();`.

---

Look at what happens when an object doesn't have a method:

```
    [~] perl -e'my $dbh = bless {}, q/foo/; $dbh->disconnect();'
    Can't locate object method "disconnect" via package "foo" at -e line 1.
```

Compared to when you're calling that method on the bareword "dbh":

```
    [~] perl -e'dbh->disconnect();'
    Can't locate object method "disconnect" via package "dbh" (perhaps you forgot to load "dbh"?) at -e line 1.
```

Comment: Happens to all of us!  Especially to me, actually...  ;)